# Facebook Subscribe Button for Pages

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible to implement a [Facebook Subscribe Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) for a Facebook Page rather than a user profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Yes. Just put in your page's username instead of a person's username.</s>

No. Use the [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) instead.

Comment: Really? cos the docs say that doesn't work, and it produces an error message

Comment: I think the Like button or Like Box is what the OP needs to use, and the Subscribe button only works with profiles
To clarify, i tried to create a subscribe button for a page and got an error message

Comment: I made a test page too. Something to run up the flagpole: The docs aren't really clear that the Subscribe plugin only works for a user.

Comment: To be fair, it does say `href - profile URL of the user to subscribe to. This must be a facebook.com profile URL` on the docs page